# Echo product title in woo commerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

At the bottom of every product I want to add the sentence:

> Any Questions about "Product Name", get in touch with us

The code I'm using is

```
<h1>Questions about <?php the_product); ?> get in touch</h1>
```

This however doesn't seem to work, how do I pull the product name in Woocommerce?

Comment: Would `<?php echo $the_product; ?>` work for you?

Comment: Where do you set the variable $the_product?

Comment: looks like you're not actually `echo`-ing the variable (assuming it has the correct content)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's outdated question, but if anybody is looking like me these days:

```
<? echo $product->post->post_title; ?>
```

or get full html title element:

```
<? echo woocommerce_template_single_title(); ?>
```

Works for Woocommerce 2.5+

Comment: Cheers! Could even be a little shorter with `<?= $product->post->post_title; ?>`

Comment: @Awilson089 PHP's short open tag is deprecated long ago.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this line

```
<h1>"Any Questions about "<?php echo $the_product; ?>", get in touch with us"</h1>
```

Note that `echo` use to print the PHP variables value, and every variable in PHP have `$` before its name like $the_product.

Comment: This doesn't return the title, surely the title is stored in a certain field of the database and I can just pull it with the woo commerce product equivalent of <?php the_title ?>

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use for my product page markups.

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">{
 "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "<?php echo the_title(); ?>",
    "category": "Designer Fashion Boutique",
    "description": "Designer Clothing Store and Online Fashion Boutique",
 "url": "<?php the_permalink(); ?>"},
        
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this official solution

```
function woocommerce_template_loop_product_title() {
        echo '<h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
    }
```

https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_template_loop_product_title.html#742-747

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $args = array('post_type' => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' =>-1);
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            if($loop->have_posts()){
                        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; echo $product->get_title(); 
endwhile;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php the_title(); ?>   //just like this
```

Answer (score -2):

You only need to `echo the_title();` of the product, like any post or page. And where did you get `$the_product` variable?